# Gmail: I send myself a file to keep in a label forever, but then I delete my sents and it deletes from my label. Help?

Tags: gmail

I have to constantly delete my sents because I send about 10 video clips (6 MEG each) per day, thus I am always filling up my free storage that Google allows. That's fine with me, I don't need to keep those sent files. What I do need to keep are files with attachments that I send myself (from other computers) so that I can keep them in labels in my iPhone and iPad Gmails for future use forever. (This is all under my one Gmail account.). But if I select all my sents, my labeled emails also get deleted. How can I stop this or find a work around?  It's painstaking (takes about 45 mins each time) to go thru each of my sents and check the ones I need to keep and the ones I can get rid of, so I'm wondering if there's another workaround rather than that obvious one.  (Yep, I send hundreds of emails per day.)

Answer (score 3):

To delete a subset of email from your sent mail while avoiding those emails you sent to yourself do the following.

1. You will need to execute a search, this can be entered in the search bar:

   ```
   is:sent to:(-youraddress@gmail.com) has:attachment
   ```

   **Note: the minus sign is crucial.**
2. You should now see all the messages that met the criteria, you sent it, but not to you, and there is an attachment. It will show you 20 messages at a time. I don't know of a way to expand this beyond 20 at a time
3. Scan the list and if it looks OK delete them.
4. If you have enabled *Quick Links* from gmail labs you can add the search string as a quick link so you don't have to remember the syntax of the search string.

Comment: Edited the query to make it in line with the OP's request (delete emails with attachments sent to self).

Comment: I had to edit it back: the key phrase is "need to keep are files with attachments that I send myself". Therefore  the search had to be for messages that I didn't send to me, then delete those messages.

Comment: Hmm. The wording is a bit weird. I thought the OP wanted to delete the 2nd copy of the email.