# Emails going into Send then into Trash and deleted rather than their designated Files

Tags: gmail

My problem: I label emails for certain files. They go into these files but also into SENT.  Now I'm afraid to move them from SENT to TRASH because they'll be deleted from TRASH when it's emptied but also from their designated files!  How can I keep these emails in their files and still be able to empty my SENT area?

Comment: Possibly related: [Gmail: I send myself a file to keep in a label forever, but then I delete my sents and it deletes from my label. Help?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28707/354)

Answer (score 1):

"Sent" is a special label in Gmail. You can't remove the "Sent" label on a message. All you can do if you want to empty your "Sent" label is delete the messages, which of course actually deletes the messages.

If you're using a label to keep track of what you've been doing, perhaps you can use a custom label ("sent-files" perhaps?) on the messages you want to track, and then remove that label when you no longer what to track that message with your label.